# Refreshing a Qt form - Seems stuck

Tags: c++, qt

My Qt form has a table and some labels. The table content and label contents changes so fast that sometimes it seems that the form is stuck. However when I minimize the form and maximize it again the latest values appear. Any suggestions on resolving this issue.

Comment: How fast is "fast"? Once per second? 10 times per second? 1000000 times per second?

Comment: thousands of times per sec

Answer (score 4):

Do not update the user interface thousands of times per second. The image you see on the display is usually updated only 60 times per second. If you have CRT display the refresh rate may be something like 50 Hz - 120 Hz, but in most displays the refresh rate is 60 Hz.

There is absolutely no need to update contents of labels more often than the display's refresh rate is. The content is never seen. But updating the user interface widgets is quite costly, so it is expected that the window seems to be frozen. You are doing a lot of unnecessary work.

Do not update the widgets every time that your data changes. Use a [timer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#startTimer) to update the widgets. Timer interval of 16 ms means that the widgets are updated about 60 times per second. But even slower update rate is most probably good enough.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is using [`repaint()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#repaint) after chaning the items:

> Repaints the widget directly by calling paintEvent() immediately,
>   unless updates are disabled or the widget is hidden.
>
> We suggest only using repaint() if you need an immediate repaint, for
>   example during animation. In almost all circumstances update() is
>   better, as it permits Qt to optimize for speed and minimize flicker.

Instead of direct calling, you can connect a signal to that widget, because `repaint()` is a slot.

Answer (score 0):

My crystal ball suggests that you are using a custom model for a `QTableWidget`, yet your custom model does not emit the `dataChanged` signal properly. Your post does not contain enough data -- what kind of "a table" are you using, and how do you provide data to it?

Comment: I provide data to it using `setItem` and then changing/updating data using `setText` of a particular item

Answer (score 0):

Completely agree with Roku answer. There is no need to update user interface with a speed faster then user can read it. I doubt that something which is more 2-3 times per second has any sense for update.. Ok, if you using smart delegates like progress bars in grid or other visual things you can go up to 5-10 times a second.. but still it's never a point to implement grid updates 1000 times a second